# RedirectMatch in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How could I modify

```
RedirectMatch ^/?folder/(.*) https://elsewhere.com/abc.php?var=1\&d=$1
```

to add an exception, so that if the address is folder/printer then it does not redirect, but everything else does?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^/?folder/printer/
```

above (!) your `RedirectMatch` should do the trick.

Also, have a look at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/189666/make-exception-to-whole-site-redirectmatch-rule)

Comment: My Apache config currently has some problem with RewriteRule that my hosting is debugging.  In the mean time, I cannot use RewriteRule but I can use Redirect and RedirectMatch.  Is there a way to implement it with RedirectMatch - preferably in that single line statement?

Comment: @lioman Ok, I see... I'm actually pretty bad at regex, but it should be something like this: `RedirectMatch ^/?folder/((?!printer$).*) https://elsewhere.com/abc.php?var=1\&d=$1` - Try some variations (like adding a slash after printer or removing the `$` there) and I hope it helps.